# Why this code causes infinite loop?

Tags: query-posts, page-template

Hi all I have this template page which get the page's post and then a list of posts from the category news.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: News & Info
 */

get_header();
?>


<div id="cLeft">
    <?php
    if (function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
        yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumb">', '</p>');
    }
    ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

            <div id="title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="freetext">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
            <?php query_posts('cat=32'); ?>

            <div class="post">
                <h2><a href=""></a></h2>
                <div class="postDescr"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>

</div>

<div id="cRight">
    <h2>News &amp; Info:</h2>

    <ul id="submenu">
        <?php wp_list_pages('hide_empty=0&child_of=26&title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'); ?> 
    </ul>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The second loop gets in infinite loop and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe because you're calling query_posts() inside the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was correctly pointed out what the issue is, but I also want to explain it so you have better idea of mechanics:

- when you use `query_posts()` it writes down generated `WP_Query` object into global `$wp_query` variable;
- `have_posts()` and `the_post()` functions are wrappers for methods of same name called using global `$wp_query` object;
- so what you are doing in that code is keep overwriting `$wp_query` and keep asking it if there are posts to process. And there are always posts because as soon as you process post you kick query back to new clean state.

Also see [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with One Trick Pony.. what if you try this?

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
            <div id="title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="freetext">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=32'); //or category_name=
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>
            <div class="post">
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
```